# Godot 4 can't select some tiles in tileset

Tags: godot, godot4

I created a tileset resource with a new atlas. I then tried to select all the tiles, but wasn't able to select tiles in the very right column of the tileset and in the last row of the tileset. Below is a picture of the issue I am facing.
I tried to fix the issue as suggested by SilicDev by increasing the sprite size. After increasing the sprite size I was able to select the greyed out tiles, but unfortunatley all tiles are out of order now. When for example I want to select the street lantern, part of the flower pot is selected too because they now after resizing the sprite share the same tile. Does anybody know a way to fix that?
[image: Whenever I click on a tile I want to add nothing happens.]
[image: Street lantern shares tile with flower pot]

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell on the picture, but how big is your atlas? It seems like there aren't 16 pixels left on the right side to make a new tile.

Comment: Yes I think thats it. How can I make the atlas bigger?

Comment: Just increasing the size of the sprite to the next multiple of 16 should allow you to select the tile. (i.e. from 250 to 256)

Comment: Hi SilcDev, unfortunatley after resizing the sprite, some objects now share the same tile. (Picture above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help at the Godot forum. I originally tried to increase the sprite size in photoshop, which didn't work out well because I couldn't choose in which direction the sprite should increase in size. Now I used Aesprite to increase the size of the spritesheet and it works now :) Thank you for your help!